# far <= mid >= near or Order of Operator Precedence in MT4?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

When implementing a simple method of reversal detection in MQL4 for +DI/-DI indicator lines in a customized Average Directional Index indicator [[ref at Investopedia]](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/adx.asp) [[full source code]](https://github.com/fxtatools/libMTA/blob/main/Libraries/libMTA/libADX.mq4#L510) I'd tried using the following expression for testing whether r<sub>1</sub> <= r<sub>2</sub> >= r<sub>3</sub> for r<sub>1</sub> being the rate at the oldest time-series tick of the three:

```cpp
if (rate_far <= rate_mid >= rate_near) {
// ...
}
```

This did not work out as hoped. Candidly, it took me a minute or to two to debug this.

Implemented as with the following expression, it works out:

```cpp
if (rate_far <= rate_mid && rate_mid >= rate_near) {
// ...
}
```

Could it possibly be a quirk of the MQL4 compiler? or have I misunderstood the operator precedence here?

Testing this in iPython, the original expression is interpreted as expected

```py
20 <= 25 >= 15
# => True
```

Comment: Have you checked the Documentation for [Precedence Rules](https://docs.mql4.com/basis/operations/rules)? MQL4 is not like Python, it does not support expressions like this as you have found out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have something to with *operator overloading* in MQL4.

Perhaps this may be similar to how it's been implemented in some standards of the C++ language.